# Can't click on quick-access after I moved Desktop + Documents + Downloads from C drive to D

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-quick-access

I have 2 drives currently: C which is 111GB SSD and D which is ~500GB HDD. Because the only thing I want on my C drive are OS-related stuff (Such as the OS itself, windows 10 of course and Virtual machines that I'm using - VM ware + Ubuntu64) I moved the entire Desktop, Downloads, Documents folders from C to D because I saw that they took some heavy amount of space.. This created some problems at the beginning, because I couldn't click on Microsoft-based files such as .docx word files etc.. (Then after a quick reset to the PC it got fixed)

However, one thing that still bothers me, is that when I open the file explorer, there is this Quick access tab, and on those file (with arrows) I can't click, because I moved them from drive C: to D:, and I think they "don't know about this change", try to access on the C: and can't find them.

[image]

This is a picture of the new location of the desktop:

[image]

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Close all Explorer Windows. Open just one Explorer Window. Right Click on Quick Access, and select Options. In the General Tab, go to the bottom, and clear Quick Access.  Close, restart the computer and test.

Comment: @AskComp FYI: Once you have removed the incorrect Quick Access link you can reenable Quick Access in the same menu.

Comment: @AskComp - Please [edit] your question to include a screenshot of Folder Options.

Comment: @Ramhound Options of what folder?

Comment: @John Thanks! It cleared my Quick access- now when files will fill up the quickaccess I will be able to click on them? One more question sir, was it a "smart move" to move the desktop (and downloads + documents) to D drive where I have a lot of space (but its HDD) rather than keep it in C drive (less space, SSD, faster)? Thanks!

Comment: @AskComp - Folder Options within File Explorer.  Please avoid asking additional questions within a comment.  All commentary is temporary.

Comment: Now that it is cleared you should be able to click on (use) the items in quick access.  In answer to your other question, I keep my document on Drive C and make sure there is enough space for that.

Answer (score 0):

> However, one thing that still bothers me, is that when I open the file explorer, there is this Quick access tab, and on those file (with arrows) I can't click, because I moved them from drive C: to D:, and I think they "don't know about this change", try to access on the C: and can't find them.

[John](https://superuser.com/questions/1617009/cant-click-on-quick-access-after-i-moved-desktop-documents-downloads-from-c#comment2466515_1617009) indicated this within a comment but you have to use File Explorer `Folder Options` to clear invalid Quick Access entries.

[image]

You can access `Folder Options` by using `Options -> change folder and search options` on the View tab within any File Explorer window.